# File allocation table (FAT8) implementation error in C++?

Tags: c++, file, file-io, fat

I am trying to simulate FAT8 [File_Allocation_Table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table). FAT  entries varies from -1 to 255 inclusive. Directory entry contains starting address of FAT table for a particular directory.

Whenever the starting address is greater than 127 then it's give a negative number. Negative number can be converted to +ve number by using offset. But the problem become hard for me when entry contains -1 and 255 since both gives same value.

How to handle this case ?

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#define SIZE 256 
using namespace std;

struct Dir{
    char fname[SIZE]; //File Name 
    char start;//1st entry in FAT
    char end;//Last entry in FAT
}dir;

char FAT[SIZE];
int NoOfFile;
char dfname[ ]="dir.txt";

int main(){
    ofstream fout;
    ifstream fin;
    char name[256];
    cout<<"Enter file name\n";
    cin>>name;
    dir.start=255;
    dir.end=3;
    strcpy(dir.fname,name);

    fout.open(dfname);
    fout.write((char*)&dir,sizeof(dir));
    fout.close();

    fin.open(dfname);
    fin.read((char*)&dir,sizeof(dir));
    cout<<dir.fname<<" "<<(int)dir.start<<" "<<(int)dir.end<<"\n";
    fin.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A char can hold 1 of 256 values.  Sounds like you are trying to store 1 of 257.

Comment: Where did you get "-1 to 255 inclusive" from? (It's impossible.)

Comment: @molbdnilo -1 is for empty location and end of links and 255 is last address in FAT .